# Find difference quotient for $f(x) = \sin x$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I need to use the different quotient:

$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$

to show that

$f(x) = \sin(x)$

simplifies to

$\cos(x) \frac{\sin(h)}{h} + \sin(x)  \frac{\cos(h)-1}{h}$

How do I do that? I already have, working from the start point,

$\frac{\sin(x)\cos(h)+\cos(x)\sin(h)-\sin(x)}{h}$

but I don't know where to go from there. Thank you!

EDIT:

Following a hint from the first comment, I now have

$\frac{(\sin(x))(\cos(h) - 1)}{h} + \frac{\cos(x)\sin(h)}{h}$

Comment: first step: Switch the second and third term in the numerator and factor out $sinx$. Then you need to split the fraction into two fractions.

Comment: What is a limit notation?

Comment: I deleted that part, you are not "there" yet :)

Comment: @imranfat Ah gotcha. I factored it. Now what?

Comment: In both fractions, but the $cosx$ and the $sinx$ "upfront".

Comment: @imranfat I did?

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/75151/169852) may be helpful.

Comment: @Bungo I'm sorry but I don't understand how :(

Comment: Oops, scratch that. I misread the question. It is only asking for the difference quotient, not the derivative (limit the of difference quotient as $h$ approaches $0$).

Comment: @Bungo Ah gotcha. So how could my question be answered?

Comment: It seems to me that you already have the answer. Your goal is $$\cos(x)\frac{\sin(h)}{h} + \sin(x)\frac{\cos(h) - 1}{h}$$ and you have $$\frac{\sin(x)(\cos(h)-1)}{h} + \frac{\cos(x)\sin(h)}{h}$$ These are the same thing, written slightly differently.

Comment: @Bungo That looks like more than slightly differently to me. What am I missing?

Comment: In the second expression, write the two terms in the opposite order. Then pull the $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ outside of the fraction.

Comment: Don't overthink this. The expression $\frac{2x}{5}$ is the same thing as $2*\frac{x}{5}$ In your case, it's the same thing

Comment: @imranfat I feel like a moron but thank you so much I got it now! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things are much easier if we choose to use [Prosthaphaeresis Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html),

$$\sin(x+h)-\sin x=2\sin\dfrac h2\cos\dfrac{2x+h}2$$

and use $\lim_{u\to0}\dfrac{\sin u}u=1$